# Can I modify pd.Series.value_counts so that by default `dropna=False`?

Tags: python, pandas

When using `pd.Series.value_counts` I almost always add the parameter `dropna=False`. Is there a simple way to set this as the default value without creating a separate function?

I ([among others](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21890)) am also curious about an explanation for why the default value is set to `True` in the first place.

```
import pandas as pd; import numpy as np

# initialize series
s = pd.Series([1,1,2,3,np.nan])

# would like s.value_counts() to have the same output as s.value_counts(dropna=False)
s.value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you can also create a shorthand method like this `pd.Series.vc = lambda x: x.value_counts(dropna=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the parameters of `pd.Series.value_counts`:

```py
print(pd.Series.value_counts.__annotations__)
# Ouput
{'normalize': 'bool', 'sort': 'bool', 'ascending': 'bool', 'dropna': 'bool'}
```

And the associated default values:

```py
print(pd.Series.value_counts.__defaults__)
# Ouput
(False, True, False, None, True)
```

So, you can change them so that the default value for `dropna` becomes **False**:

```py
pd.Series.value_counts.__defaults__ = (False, True, False, None, False)

print(s.value_counts())
# Output
1.0    2
2.0    1
3.0    1
NaN    1
```